# air bag light after seat removal repair

Tags: nissan, supplemental-restraint-system, maxima

I needed to remove the passenger seat to weld a hole in the floor. I disconnected the battery, the wires to the seat and removed it. After re-installing the seat and the battery , my air-bag light started flashing. I tried to re-set the computer  by battery disconnected and waiting 10 min. but it did nothing. I have active head restraints and air-bags in the seat.
2004 Nissan maxima

Answer (score 4):

I found these directions for resetting the SRS after the dash light starts blinking. It is from [this website](http://www.nicoclub.com/archives/maxima-airbag-light.html):

> 1. Open the driver’s door.
> 2. Note the rubber covered button located low on the B pillar, a button which is pressed by the door when the door is closed. This is the Driver’s Door Switch (DDS).
> 3. Turn the ignition from OFF to ON.
> 4. Press the DDS at least 5 times within 7 seconds after turning the ignition switch ON.
> 5. Turn the ignition OFF.
> 6. Close the driver’s door.
> 7. Start the engine.
>
> If the airbag warning lamp is still on (or still flashing), there is a fault in the Supplemental Restraint System which must be diagnosed and repaired. This is a job for your local friendly Nissan dealer.

I'm sure a reset will fix your issue, as I doubt (though don't know for sure) you have caused any permanent damage to your system by disconnecting the seat harness. I post this because it is quite different than what has been posted already and I found it in several places on the web. Hope it helps.

Comment: This actually worked. I wiggled the connectors under the driver's seat working the male to female plugs together, then did the key trick watching the clock to the second. After the 5th cycle, I switched the ignition on and the light slowed to indicate it was in diagnostic mode. I let it self-check for a full minute, then switched the ignition off, then BACK ON after 5 seconds. Without starting the car, the light extinguished and stayed out. After a full minute I restarted the car, and the light again STAYED OUT. 328k miles, and that damn light had been on for 2 and a half years. 2010 Versa Hat

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much, just did this for my Nissan Juke and I followed your directions and the light has switched off. Thanks so much. The seat belt light started flashing because I changed the battery and checked the radio fuse and that bleeding flickering symbol was driving me nuts. Happy lady here.

Answer (score 0):

The air bag system checks itself every time you turn on the ignition. If the air bag light was going out after 7 seconds every time you turned on the ignition before the welding was carried out but not afterwards, it suggests that the wires may have been burnt/damaged by the welding. Try the following before anything else. It is for resetting the airbag system without a service tool.

1. Turn ignition switch “ON”.
2. After “AIR BAG” warning lamp lights for 7 seconds, and starts flashing, turn ignition switch “OFF” within 1 second. DO NOT SWITCH IT TO LOCK, SWITCH IT TO ACC
3. Wait more than 3 seconds.
4. Repeat steps 1 to 3 two times. Perform 3 times in total.
5. Turn ignition switch “ON”. SRS is now in Diagnosis mode.
   In diagnosis mode, you’re going to hope the light flashes slowly.2 seconds off, 3 seconds on, and repeats.If your light does this, this means that the computer detected a previous error that hasn’t been erased.This is good.
6. If “AIR BAG” warning lamp now operates 2 secs off 3 secs on, turn ignition switch “OFF” to reset from Diagnosis mode and to erase the memory.
7. Turn ignition “ON”. “AIR BAG” warning lamp should operate like normal.